# Show a div only once per day

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have created a code with cookies for showing up a div, just once per day. I don't know why my browser displays me in the console that "Undefined is not a function".
Can you help me?

```
if($.cookie('showOnlyOnce', 1)){
    $('#loading').hide();
} else {
    $.cookie('showOnlyOnce', 1, { expires: 1 });
    $('#loading').show();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `undefined`?

Comment: The first line http://gyazo.com/9a162bc0dc4505c78ed77e4eb8768b6c

Comment: "The first line" can't be `undefined`. There is a function in the first line that is `undefined`. What is that function? If it's the `$.cookie` do you include the plugin file in your document? jQuery core doesn't  have such function!

Comment: Do I have toi use JQuery UI? or something like that? Another version? I just have JQuery 1.11.2 and JQuery migrate

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't have `$.cookie`. Here is the plugin github repo: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: you could try simple js cookies link : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp